# How do you include CGAL into a QT project in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, cgal

I am trying to run some of the sample example code from [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) as a Qt project, to run in Qt Creator.  I expect that I will have to modify the `.pro` file.  How should it be modified to use CGAL libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CGAL specifically, but *in general*, you would need to add the following to your `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/cgal/headers

LIBS += -Lpath/to/cgal/libraries -lcgal_dll_name
```

You may also need to add some `DEFINES` if CGAL requires it, i.e.

```
DEFINES += SOME_MACRO_THAT_CGAL_REQUIRES
```

If you were looking for help on CGAL specifically, please clarify your question and I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, just for the sake of having a more complete answer, this is what I had to do in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=   /usr/include/
LIBS        += -L/usr/include/
LIBS        += -lCGAL
LIBS        += -lgmp
LIBS        += -lmpfr // not really needed for me, but added since gmp had to be added too
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -frounding-math -O3
```

Do **NOT** add stuff like the following, it will get you into trouble with weird error messages, as discussed in [this link](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Trouble-with-Examples-td952584.html).

```
INCLUDEPATH +=   /usr/include/CGAL # do NOT add this!
LIBS        += -L/usr/include/CGAL # do NOT add this!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt 4.8.6, gcc and Fedora 24, and here is my .pro for Qt-CGAL projects :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-01-08T14:50:29
#
#-------------------------------------------------    
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = My CGAL_test
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lgmp -lmpfr -lCGAL

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```